# Gmaps : Need to make getDistanceMatrix call for synchronous

Tags: javascript, maps, synchronous

In my application, I need to set the coordinates of markers along with distances in a hidden field then submit this hidden field(which is a bean property) via a form.
Now for this I've added a button on my form on the click of which a script is called that populates the field with markers coords & the action of this button submits the form.
**The issue here is when my javascript is called it makes an asynchronous call to DistanceService & continues to my button's action handler method. In this handle method I need the hidden field to be populated. So the hidden field gets populated after the control reaches my handler method ie. the callback happens after my form is submitted.**

I am using ICEFaces JSF + Spring + Gmaps v3.

This is the button:

```
<h:commandButton value="Add Markers" onclick="saveMarkersToBean(this.id);" action="#{myBean.saveMarkers}"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
~Nilesh